# Private VLAN on HP switch

Tags: hp, private-vlan

I am totally new to vlan concept and I am trying to learn by configuring them on these 2 switches: HP-2530-24G and HP-1820-8G(where there is no CLI).
I need to implement Private-Vlan on these switches , but I do not find any documentation if they support private vlan or how to configure them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all HP series support Private VLAN (PVLAN). According to [HPE ArubaOS-Switch Software Feature Support Matrix](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=a00038733en_us), you do not have this feature (PVLAN) on your devices.

Some people [suggest that](https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProCurve-ProVision-Based/HP-2910al-and-private-VLAN/td-p/2358005) you can use [source-port filters](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/Security-Oct2005-59906024-Chap10-Traf-Security-Filts.pdf).

Comment: Could I use Pvlan edge ?

Comment: Is there a list stating which hp models support pvlan?

Comment: @Innov Please check the link `HPE ArubaOS-Switch Software Feature Support Matrix` in my answer.